# Error: "Could not import 'flaskProject'" after "flask run" and "Fatal Python error: init_stdio_encoding: failed to ..." after clicking run button

Tags: python, flask

I was following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo) on python flask tutorial.

I coded my virtual environment in Pycharm and I followed the video(on 7:58mins) and typed in `SET FLASK_APP=flaskProject.py` where flaskProject is my project name.

However, when I typed in `flask run`, it returned this message:

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.
```

And then seeing my main code is called `app.py`, I typed in `SET FLASK_APP=app.py`.
However, this time it returned `Error: Could not import 'flaskProject'.`
I tried `FLASK_APP=Scripts/app.py` and `Set FLASK_ENVIRONMENT=development` even tried including the full address(`set FLASK_APP=C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\flaskProject.py`) but it still didn't work.

After looking at similar questions in Stack overflow, I tried clicking the run button instead of typing `flask run` in terminal. But it returned a long error message:

```
Fatal Python error: init_stdio_encoding: failed to get the Python codec name of the stdio encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: unknown encoding: x-windows-950

Current thread 0x00004864 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you ot the cmd in the same directory as your file ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my cmd is in "(venv) PS C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\FLask_Blog>
". However, after adding app.py into the directory Flask_Blog, it still didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried: SET FLASK_APP=app

Comment: Just app without .py